# My app crash when I receive a push and the app was close by the user

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to test in x-code how to close my app by double tapping the home button and swipe up the app, and close it. Then I would tap on the push notification to open again the app. My problem is, when the app is closed this way and I receive and tap on the push notification, the app crashes before open. I need to handle this so that's the reason of my question.

Comment: Have you looked at the crash log?

Comment: There is no crash lo since I can't do this from x-code. This is the goal of the question, how to simulare this situation from x-code

Comment: What? Your question states that the app crashes. Now your comment says there is no crash. Which is it? If there is a crash, then there is a crash log - whether you use Xcode or not.

Comment: I said there is no crash log, no there is no crash...  the app is not running from x-code, but from the device directly.

Comment: Hos can i check the crash log if Im not running the app from xcode?

Comment: Now you are saying there is no crash log and no crash. If there is no crash, then what is the problem? Why does your question say there is a crash but both of your comments say there is no crash? If your app really is crashing on a device, then there will be a crash log. You don't need Xcode to get a crash log.

Comment: I never said there is no crash.. I only said no crash log.. Since you came into this post, you are asking things that are allready explained above.. Do you really know to read? Stop asking silly things and answer how to get into this crash log. This is for give answers to people, not to ask things that are allready writen above... If you can't help then stop anoying people saying they said this or that and leave.Thanks

Comment: 1) Sync your device to your computer with iTunes. The crash log will be on your computer. 2) Read your first comment. You said "no crash", not "no crash log", hence the confusion.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your answers and sorry for my english and my last comment